# Иерархии в базе T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

Только начал изучать T-SQL и натолкнулся на вопрос
"Как объявить хранение иерархии в таблице?"
Подскажите, куда копать,  чтобы разобраться  с этим. Я так понимаю имеем ввиду нереляционную базу, в которой сущности связаны древовидно. Исправьте, если не так

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замечательный пример есть на stackoverflow. Для сбора всей необходимой информации в таблице используем выражение WITH: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx.

```
-- Создаем таблицу с полями, где ParentID - это ссылка на поле ID этой же таблицы
CREATE TABLE tblHierarchy (ID int, ParentID int NULL, Name varchar(max));

-- Заполнение тестовыми данными
INSERT INTO tblHierarchy VALUES (1, NULL, '1');
INSERT INTO tblHierarchy VALUES (2, NULL, '2');
INSERT INTO tblHierarchy VALUES (3, NULL, '3');
INSERT INTO tblHierarchy VALUES (4, 1, '1.1');
INSERT INTO tblHierarchy VALUES (5, 1, '1.2');
INSERT INTO tblHierarchy VALUES (6, 4, '1.1.1');

WITH Parent AS
(
    -- Часть запроса выберет записи верхнего уровня, у которых нет ParentID
    SELECT
        ID,
        ParentID,
        Name AS Path
    FROM
        tblHierarchy
    WHERE
        ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    -- Эта часть запроса рекурсивно выберет все остальные строки и с помощью
    -- нехитрого CONVERT(...) в последний столбец запишет строку иерархии
    SELECT
        TH.ID,
        TH.ParentID,
        CONVERT(varchar(128), Parent.Path + '/' + TH.Name) AS Path
    FROM
        tblHierarchy TH
    INNER JOIN
        Parent
    ON
        Parent.ID = TH.ParentID
)
SELECT * FROM Parent
```

На выходе получаем:

```
ID  ParentID    Path
1   NULL        1
2   NULL        2
3   NULL        3
4   1       1/1.1
5   1       1/1.2
6   4       1/1.1/1.1.1
```